# A faster way to solve this mixture problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We want to create $\text{Mixture X}$ which contains 12% of $\text{Substance 1}$, 20% of $\text{Substance B}$ and 68% of $\text{Substance C}$. But we only have these mixtures available:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} 
 & \text{Substance 1} & \text{Substance 2} & \text{Substance 3} \\ \hline
\text{Mixture A} & \text{10%} & \text{10%} & \text{80%} \\ \hline
\text{Mixture B} & \text{10%} & \text{20%} & \text{70%} \\ \hline
\text{Mixture C} & \text{20%} & \text{30%} & \text{50%} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

How much of each mixture do we need to produce $\text{Mixture X}$?

1. $A = \text{20%}, B = \text{40%}, C = \text{40%}$
2. $A = \text{20%}, B = \text{60%}, C = \text{20%}$
3. $A = \text{30%}, B = \text{50%}, C = \text{20%}$
4. $A = \text{25%}, B = \text{30%}, C = \text{45%}$

---

What I did was this:

- Check Mixture A for answer 1: $(10 * 0.2) + (10 * 0.4) + (20 * 0.4) = 14$, so answer 1 gives the wrong percentage for Mixture A, so it's out.
- Check Mixture A for answer 2: $(10 * 0.2) + (10 * 0.6) + (20 * 0.2) = 12$, so this can be a solution, but need to check other substances for answer 2.
- ... and so on ...

This was rather time consuming, because there are many numbers and it's easy to make a mistake.

If I remember correctly, I concluded answer 3 is correct, but it took quite a while. Is there a better method than calculating every single value one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a faster and more systematic way.  Let the proportions of mixtures A, B, C that comprise mixture X be $a, b, c$.  Then Mixture $X$ contains proportions $0.1 a + 0.1 b + 0.2 c$ of Substance 1, $0.1 a + 0.2 b + 0.3 c$ of Substance 2, and $0.8 a + 0.7 b + 0.5 c$ of Substance 3.  Since the desired proportions of each substance in Mixture X are $0.12$, $0.2$, and $0.68$ respectively, we have the resulting system (after multiplying by $10$)
$$\begin{align*} 
a + b + 2c &= 1.2 \\ 
a + 2b + 3c &= 2 \\
8a + 7b + 5c &= 6.8. \end{align*}$$  Subtracting the first equation from the second gives $$b + c = 0.8,$$ and subtracting the third equation from eight times the first gives $$b + 11c = 2.8.$$ Therefore, $10c = 2$, or $c = 0.2$, and $b = 0.6$, from which we readily obtain $a = 1.2 - 2(0.2) - 0.6 = 0.2$.  Note that the original presumption was that $a, b, c$ represent proportions making up a whole, so in fact, the above system could include an additional constraint, $$a + b + c = 1.$$  Including this extra constraint would make the system overdetermined, but the point is that we can eliminate any other equation, and the third one is obviously the most complicated one; so we could have instead solved 
$$\begin{align*} 
a + b + c &= 1 \\
a + b + 2c &= 1.2 \\ 
a + 2b + 3c &= 2. \\
\end{align*}$$
This system is very simple; the first two equations immediately gives us $c = 0.2$, and then by substitution into the third, $a + 2b = 2 - 3(0.2) = 1.4$.  Similarly, substitution into the first gives $a + b = 1 - 0.2 = 0.8$, hence $b = 0.6$, and the rest follows.

---

It is worth mentioning to more advanced students familiar with matrix algebra that what we have here is the matrix equation $$\boldsymbol x \boldsymbol M = \boldsymbol y,$$ where $\boldsymbol x = (a,b,c)$ is a row vector, $$\boldsymbol M = \begin{bmatrix} 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.8 \\ 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.7 \\ 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.5 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $\boldsymbol y = (0.12, 0.2, 0.68)$.  Thus we can solve for $\boldsymbol x$ by inverting $\boldsymbol M$, namely $$\boldsymbol x = \boldsymbol y \boldsymbol M^{-1}.$$  But as I noted above, the simpler system $$\boldsymbol x \boldsymbol M^* = \boldsymbol y^*$$ with $$\boldsymbol M^* = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \\  1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}, \quad \boldsymbol y^* = (1, 1.2, 2)$$ is slightly easier to work with, and rather than computing the matrix inverse, it is also easier to do the computation using Gauss-Jordan elimination.

Comment: Very interesting solution. What area of mathematics is this, so I can learn more about that? Btw. the timelimit on that question was 4 min.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**
Check the techniques of linear programming.
(Some linear algebra books has a section dedicated to this)